# Xamarin Studio Monogame.Framework.dll Reference Error

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monogame, xamarin-studio

When I create a brand new iOS Monogame project the references Lidgren.Network and MonoGame.Framework can't be found.  So I delete them and then in edit references I go to Library/Application Support/XamarinStudio-4.0/LocalInstall/Addins/MonoDevelop.Monogame.3.0.1 and attempt to select Monogame.Framework.dll and Lindgren.Network.dll and get the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It seems like a "file not found" error but the files are obviously there because I can select them in the folder?  Does anyone have any advice?  Am I overlooking something easy?

Comment: Did you target your project to .NET Framework 2.0?

Comment: It seems the error is due to a missing MonoGame.Framework.dll reference.  Not with a build yet.

Comment: Well, the error says: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0` which is related to .NET Framework

Comment: So I pulled down MonoGame.zip project from Git and built the iOS/MonoGame.Framework project and then references the dll's created from that and it seemed to work.  Not sure why referencing the other dll threw a file not found exception for system.core.

Comment: I've been googling about and that seems to be a bug [Bugzilla]https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10755

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Lingren.Network and MonoGame.Framework
2. Import /Users/*username*/Library/Application Support/XamarinStudio-4.0/LocalInstall/Addin/MonoDevelop.MonoGame.3.0.1/assemblies/iOS/Lingren.Network.dll
3. Same location MonoGame.Framework.dll